# For Loop and Sum

Tags: homework

I am requested to do a sum of the first fifty positive even numbers by using `For` loop. 
The `For` loop that I created is

```
For[natNum = 2, natNum <= 50, natNum = natNum + 2, Print[natNum]]
```

The output of this is a list of numbers from 2 to 50 and they are increasing by 2. Now I need these numbers to be sum so I created

```
Sum[For[natNum = 2, natNum <= 50, natNum = natNum + 2, Print[natNum]]]
```

However, it is not a correct input. I am not sure if I should write the `Sum` inside the `For` loop.

Comment: If this is a class assignment, I'd suggest withdrawing from the class. `For` loops are almost never a good way to do anything in *Mathematica*.

Comment: If you want the first 50 positive even numbers, I believe that is {2, 4, ..., 100}.  The sum is (2+100) + (4+98) + ...  + (50 + 52) = 102 * 25 = 2550.

Comment: `Total@Range[2, 2*50, 2]` would be pretty direct. Note also that `Print` *prints* its arguments, but does not *return* them (in fact, it returns `Null`).

Comment: Since the days of Carl Friedrich Gauß we know that using a `For` loop to compute `50 * 51` is a pretty bad idea....

Comment: Is it the first fifty that you want, or is it {2, 4, ..., 50}?  The original question had both.

Answer (score 12):

Anyone asking you to write `For` loops in Mathematica for such a problem is a dolt.  Nevertheless, here's how you might do that:

```
rslt = 0;
For[i = 0, i <= 50, i += 2, rslt += i];
rslt
```

And here's how someone with some familiarity with Mathematica might write it

```
Plus @@ Range[25]*2
```

Now, spend the time you were going to waste writing a `For` loop by reading the answers to this question [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The first fifty positive integers can be computed with `Table`:

```
Q = 0; (* Initialization *)
T = Table[Q + k, {k, 2 Range[50]}]
```

[image: output of the above code]

We can sum up the values of `T` with `Sum`:

```
Sum[T[[k]], {k, Range[50]}]
```

2550

Comment: Perhaps better / more idiomatic than your `Sum` approach would be using `Total[T]` or `Plus@@T`.

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for something like `Total` and I saw the `Plus` posting above, but haven't yet learned about `@@` and such.  I would have thought `Map` might work here (it does not).  Anyway, yes `Total[T]` and `Plus@@T` are simpler and more elegant!

Comment: I was a latecomer to `@@` as well. When I was learning about it, it helped me to think about it as a way of "swapping heads" of expressions. So for instance, if you have `{1, 2, 3}`, its `FullForm` would be `List[1, 2, 3]`. If you then `Apply` `Plus` to it, i.e. `Plus@@`, you swap the `List`head for a `Plus` head, to give `Plus[1, 2, 3]`. Although it may *seem* like a niche application at first, once you get used to it, it is tremendously useful!

Comment: This is great, thank you!  Just as I learned not to use `For` loops (especially on this `For`um), and to `Do` use `Do`, I'll look for opportunities to `Apply` `@@`.